# Ghost margin/padding between parent and child in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

When I have `inline-block` parent and child elements IE shows ghost space between them:

[image]

I can fix this by removing the whitespace in the html but I want to know if there is a css cross-browser solution for this.

```css
.bar {
  height: 30px;  
}

.section {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;  
}

.section::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;  
  margin-left: -.25rem;
}

span {
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="section">
    <span>
      IE ghost
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <span>
    No ghost
    </span><!-- 
--></div>
</div>
```

Comment: WHY ARE YOU USING IE???

Comment: God forbid that a developer should support the significant portion of users who use IE...

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because of the `inline` behaviour of the `inline-block`. They are treated like other inline elements where surrounding sibling elements (including spaces, text, etc.) Will be parsed as opposed to ignored.

As you stated, one solution is to remove the white-space between the affected divs which can mess with your html formatting (if you care about that).

> Solution using CSS.white-space:
>
> *If you are sure that you will not require the contents of the containing `div.bar` to wrap* then **you can set the CSS property of
>   [`.white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to nowrap**:

```
.bar { 
  height: 30px; 
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. IE shows the same result with/without `white-space: nowrap;`